# Retrieve Data From 3 Tables in YII Framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have to show member(model) except member with authentication === staff

I have 3 tables

accounts (id is the primary)
members(id is the primary, account_id is the foreignkey)
authassignment (itemname, user_id is foreignkey)

please check this picture

http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5483/11561320666_16f41c3e2c_b.jpg

Comment: give your table details, and then what you need from these tables. mean give some more info, then may be solve your problem ....

Answer (score 0):

You may use relations to set the relationships between your tables. Read this. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Answer (score 0):

I hope your tables has relations. I'm assuming you Accounts Model is with bellow relatins

```
    class Accounts extends CActiveRecord
    { 
         public function relations()
         {         
             return array(
                 'authitemRelation' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Authitem', 'account_id'),
                 'membersRelation' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Members', 'account_id'),
              );
         }
         ........
         ........

     }
```

In this case you can retrieve the details with `with()`

```
    $criteria= new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->addCondition(array('where'=>'authitem.itemname not like "staff"'));
    $data = yourAccountsModel::model()->with('authitemRelation','membersRelation')->findAll($criteria);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
```